# Javascript Object.assign() and method length

Tags: javascript

Bellow my issue. 
I have something like that :

```
console.log("nag : "+ nag.length) // nag is an object it return 512 values.
let c = Object.assign({}, nag) // i copy nag into c.
console.log(c.length) // i return 0 but i can display the content.
```

Why my copy doesnt have the same properties that my source ?

Comment: What is `nag`? An array? A string? Also, what are you trying to accomplish with the `Object.assign` line, what do you think it does? (also, `.length` is a property here, not a method) If `nag` is an object, you can create a shallow copy using `let c = {...nag};`

Comment: Assuming that `nag` is an object with a `length` property, this works just fine: `Object.assign({}, { length: 512 });`

Comment: nag.length should be undefined because objects don't have a length property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning something with a property `length` (probably an `Array`) to an `Object` (`{}`), which is unaware of such a property. The snippet should make clear how that works.

```js
{
  const nag0 = [0, 1, 2]; // an Array, has property 'length'
  const nag1 = Object.assign({}, nag0);
  const nag2 = Object.assign([], nag0);
  const yn = yn => yn ? `yep` : `nope`;
  
  console.log(`lengths:\nnag0 ${
    nag0.length}\nnag1: ${
    nag1.length}\nnag2: ${
    nag2.length}`);
  console.log(`Now, what *is* nag1?`, nag1);
  console.log(`and nag2?`, nag2);
  console.log(`Does nag1 'know' the "length"-property? ${
    yn(nag1.hasOwnProperty(`length`))}`);
  console.log(`How about nag2? ${
    yn(nag2.hasOwnProperty(`length`))}`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Object.assign()` method copies all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object.

Arrays do have a `length` property, but it is not enumerable, and so `Object.assign` ignores it.

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors([]))
```

Change your code to the following to make it "work":

```js
const nag = [{}, {}]
console.log('nag length: ', nag.length) // 2
let c = Object.assign([], nag)
console.log('new object length: ', c.length) // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok my first object was type Object but contains an array => [{},{}]
When i copy with assign the method return a {{},{},{}}

I used slice to copy